# Как обновить сущность после добавления новой записи?

Tags: c#, linq2sql

Разбираюсь с `Linq2Sql`, весьма интересная вещь. Возникла небольшая проблема. Имеется таблица бд. В `dataGridView` я отображаю её. После добавления записи в эту таблицу, необходимо чтобы обновилась сущность, и соответственно `dataGridView` её должен отобразить. Делал `Refresh` у `dataContext'a` но что то не выходит - добавленная запись не отображается.

Вот так описана таблица бд:

```
[Table(Name="Марка")]
public class Marka : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Marka(string name)
    {
        MarkaName = name;            
    }

    public Marka() { }

    int id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "Код",DbType="Int",IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    string markaname;
    [Column(Name = "Наименование")]
    public string MarkaName
    {
        get { return markaname; }
        set 
        { markaname = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("markaname"));
        }
    }public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Вот так из формы я добавляю новые записи:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataContext context;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new DataContext(@"D:\CSharp\!WPF\avtoSeller\avto.mdb");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = context.GetTable<Marka>();//отображаю в гриде таблицу
    }  
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//добавляю новую запись
    {
Marka m = new Marka("пример марки12");
        context.GetTable(typeof(Marka)).InsertOnSubmit(m);
        context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges); 
        context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Самое интересное (по крайней мере для меня), что после добавления вывожу кол-во строк

```
Text = context.GetTable<Marka>().Count().ToString()
```

в таблице, и оно увеличивается как и должно быть на 1, но почему в гриде не отображается новая запись?

Comment: вы обновляете данные, но не их представление, обновите датагрид

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource обновляйте после добавлении новой записи

Comment: просто к примеру, если для источника DGV использовать DataTable, и добавить в DataTable строку, то грид подхватит её. Думал здесь что то подобное будет. Попробовал после добавления записи вызывать опять    
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = источник.
Но новые строки не показываются

Answer (score 1):

<sub>раз уж Community поднял вопрос</sub>

`DataGridView` поддерживает три вида датасорсов:

- продвинутые, реализующие интерфейсы `IBindingListView`, `IBindingList` - они поддерживают вставку новый записей из `DataGridView`, и уведомляют `DataGridView` о вставке записей в сам датасорс.
- тупые, `IList` - просто списки объектов. Из них данные затягиваются в `DataGridView` один раз, после этого никакие изменения ни в одну из сторон не распространяются - в интерфейсе `IList` для этого нет никаких событий.
- косвенные (не уверен как назвать точнее) - `IListSource`. Это датасорсы с одним методом - `IListSource.GetList()`, и в зависимости от того, что он вернет - `IBindingList(View)` или `IList` - `DataGridView` выбирает из первых двух механизмов.

`DataTable`/`DataSet` реализуют `IListSource` с возвратом `IBindingListView`
 - класса-обертки `DataView`. Поэтому изменения в `DataTable` тут же отображаются в `DataGridView`. Кроме того, новые строки из `DataGridView` так же попадают в `DataTable`.

В случае же с L2S, вызов

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = context.GetTable<Marka>();
```

возвращает просто `IList`. В `DataGridView` практически попадает не "таблица", а просто список объектов на момент установки `dataGridView1.DataSource` - то, что в этот момент вернет `context.GetTable<Marka>().ToList()`.

Никаких уведомлений о вставке новых строк `DataGridView` не получит. Единственный способ загрузить в него изменений - вручную отдать ему новый датасорс - еще раз выполнить `dataGridView1.DataSource = context.GetTable<Marka>()`

Answer (score 0):

после dataGridView1.DataSource = ... сделай dataGridView1.DataBind(); и будет тебе счастье

Comment: такого метода нет у DGV

Comment: *лучше* использовать **System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bind**, *SqlConnection,SqlClient* (точно не помню) указываете *DataSource =bind.Datasource;*
И соответственно, *datagridview.datasource = bind.Datasource;*

логика такая.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте делать `context.Refresh` после `context.SubmitChanges()`, а не до. Сейчас вы пытаетесь читать из базы до того, как записали в нее.